# SIGSEGV from ffmpeg on Amazon Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

Trying out Amazon Lambda / nodejs 8. My goal is to launch ffmpeg, generate a short clip and upload it to S3 bucket.

I created the function following the [image resize tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). Edited the code to get output from simple linux commands like `ls` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo` - all works.

Now, added the ffmpeg binary for i686 - [ffmpeg static build](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) by JohnVan Sickle (thanks!). Changed the code to launch simple ffmpeg command that is supposed to create sa 2-seconds small video clip.

That fails, according to logs, with the signal `SIGSEGV` returned to the "[close](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_close)" event handler of [child_process.spawn()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

As far as I understand, this could be caused by the ffmpeg binary incompatibility with the static build. Or by some mistake in my code.

Several npm modules rely on the static builds from johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg and there are no such issues filed on their github. Maybe there's some other mistake I made?

Should I compile ffmpeg myself under Amazon Linux AMI `amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2` which is under the hood of AWS Lambda?

---

**upd.** Launched EC2 t2.micro instance from the same AMI, downloaded the same ffmpeg static build, and it works just fine from the command line. Now I doubt that it is a compilation issue.

Also tried copying ffmpeg executable to `/tmp/ffmpeg` and `chmod 755` just to make sure.
Running simple `ffmpeg --help` command via `child_process.execSync()` returns "Error: Command failed: /tmp/ffmpeg --help"

---

```
const join = require('path').join;
const tmpdir = require('os').tmpdir;
const process = require('process');
const fs = require('fs');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const async = require('async');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');

process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];


const tempDir = process.env['TEMP'] || tmpdir();
const filename = join(tempDir, 'test.mp4');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  var dstBucket = srcBucket + "resized";
  var dstKey  = "render-test.mp4";

  async.waterfall([
    function transform(next) {
      var args = [
        '-filter_complex',
        '"testsrc=r=25:s=640x480:d=3"',
        '-an',
        '-y',
        '-hide_banner',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        filename,
      ];

      console.log("Will launch ffmpeg");
      const childProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

      childProcess.on('close', function(e) {
        console.log('ffmpeg close event: ' + JSON.stringify(arguments));
        next();
      });

      console.log("After launched ffmpeg");
    },

    function upload(next) {
      ...
    }
  ], function (err) {
    ...
  });
};
```

Comment: I would have the Lambda execute "ffmpeg --help" initially as the most basic check of binary compatibility and exec permissions.

Comment: @jarmod I tried that as well. First I do `ls-lA` on the ffmpeg executalbe to verifythe path is correct `stdout: -rwxr-xr-x 1 slicer 497 43875308 Apr 7 12:37 /var/task/ffmpeg` and empty `stdout` and `stderr`.

Then when I try the `ffmpeg --help` it fails with error: `Error: Command failed: /var/task/ffmpeg --help`

Comment: Also tried copying the executable to `/tmp/` and `chmod 755 /tmp/ffmpeg` prior to executing - same result. The file is there, has  correct permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 sbx_user1051 495 43875308 Apr 7 18:56 /tmp/ffmpeg`,  but still `Command failed: /tmp/ffmpeg --help`

Comment: *"Should I compile ffmpeg myself under Amazon Linux AMI amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2"*  I'd say yes.  That is, to my understanding, the primary reason thst image is made available... for compiling compatible binaries.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I made another test - launched EC2 t2.micro from the AMI, and downloaded the same static build of ffmpeg. It works fine from command line.
So it might not be the build, but nodejs / Lambda restrictions that cause the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. Despite the misleading fact that static build of ffmpeg from JohnVanSickle.com does run on Amazon EC2 instance of the AMI, mentioned in [Lambda environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), same binary fails to execute under AWS Lambda.

I compiled ffmpeg on the AWS EC2 t2.micro instance of the same AMI using [markus-perl/ffmpeg-build-script](https://github.com/markus-perl/ffmpeg-build-script).  It also surprised me with an [error](https://github.com/markus-perl/ffmpeg-build-script/issues/24) of `aom` codec version. Changed one line in the script to disable the `aom` codec and ffmpeg finally has compiled. Took a couple of hours on the weak t2.micro instance.

The resulting ffmpeg binary is ~10Mb lighter than the static build mentioned above and runs on AWS Lambda just fine!

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a binary on your own, you can use ffmpeg-lambda-layer (
https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~ffmpeg-lambda-layer)

Deploy it and add it as a layer to your function. Within your function the binary can be accessed as '/opt/bin/ffmpeg'.