Segmentation Fault when calling FFMPEG on Lambda - but not locally
I am trying to extract the next 30 seconds of audio from a live video stream on YouTube using AWS Lambda. However, I'm facing an issue where Lambda does not wait for an FFmpeg subprocess to complete, unlike when running the same script locally. Below is a simplified Python script illustrating the problem:
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context, streaming_url):
    ffmpeg_command = [
        "ffmpeg", 
        "-loglevel", "error", 
        "-i", streaming_url, 
        "-t", "30", 
        "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", 
        "-ar", "44100", 
        "-ac", "2", 
        "/tmp/output.wav"
    ]

    print("Starting subprocess...")
    print(f"Start time: {datetime.now()}")
    subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command, capture_output=True)
    print(f"End time: {datetime.now()}")

In this script, I am using FFmpeg to capture audio from the specified streaming_url, converting it to a .wav format, and saving it as output.wav. When executed locally, this script waits until the subprocess finishes, evidenced by the significant time difference between the start and end print statements. However, when run on AWS Lambda, it proceeds almost immediately without waiting for the subprocess to complete, resulting in incomplete audio files.
Question: How can I ensure that AWS Lambda waits for the FFmpeg subprocess to fully execute before the function exits? I assume I'm not understanding correctly how Lambda handles subprocesses. I even tried adding a time.sleep(30) after the subprocess.run, but that didn't help. Is there a specific configuration or method to handle subprocesses in Lambda correctly?
EDIT: With the help of the comments, I understood that in fact it's returning quickly in Lambda because of a segmentation fault, since it gives me a returncode of -11, so I edited the question and its title accordingly. Locally, there is no such error. I found out this is a similar situation to Using FFmpeg with URL input causes SIGSEGV in AWS Lambda (Python runtime), but I'm still unable to solve it.

What is your Lambda function's configured timeout? Default is 3 seconds, which may be too short.

Well, for the main function it's 15 minutes, the max. I don't know if there could be a separate limite for the subprocesses called within that function, though

It might be giving an error. Can you get a response back from subprocess.run() to discover if an error was returned?

Try tweaking down how much of the video to actually process. Start really low (say, 3 seconds?) and see if that works.

Thank you all for your suggestions. I tried to do what @JohnRotenstein suggested and examine the output of subprocess.run. Locally no errors, on Lambda I see a returncode=-11, which is a segmentation fault. Now I'm trying to understand what could be causing it. BTW this led me to this similar question but no definitive answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719161/using-ffmpeg-with-url-input-causes-sigsegv-in-aws-lambda-python-runtime

It might be because AWS Lambda only allows files to be written to the /tmp/ directory. Try specifying that directory in the output parameter? Also, found this, might help: Processing user-generated content using AWS Lambda and FFmpeg | AWS for M&E Blog

Actually sorry about that, I simplified my code so much to post here that I forgot this detail, but in my actual code I do write to /tmp/, so that is not the issue here. Something like /tmp/output.wav. I will edit the question for clarity. Will check your link, thank you

You can check for messages written to standard error using p = subprocess.run(...); print(p.stderr)). And you might be able to get more details using catchsegv if it's installed -- change the command to ["catchsegv", "ffmpeg", ...].

I added catchsegv to the command, and the error code returned now is 139, which I think also just means segmentation fault.
On my search I see questions that indicate that perhaps the problem is with how I'm installing ffmpeg, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561267/sigsegv-from-ffmpeg-on-amazon-lambda.
Currently I install it with a dockerfile, with:
RUN wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz -O ffmpeg.tar.xz && \     tar -xJf ffmpeg.tar.xz --strip-components=1 -C /usr/local/bin && \     rm ffmpeg.tar.xz
